# how to prevent a mixture of "old" and "new" Bing Maps tiles

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bing-maps

The [Bing Maps blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701721.aspx) states that the "new" Bing Maps style will be implemented today.

I'm seeing a strange mixture of old and new tiles when using the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API (use [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/ve/ve_layer.html) to test, choosing the Roads option). http://www.bing.com/maps does not exhibit this problem.

[image: Bing Maps showing old and new styles]

**Questions**

1) am I just unlucky in trying this exactly as ESRI/Microsoft are changing the tiles over? (ie, does it work differently for you?)

2) if not, how can I force my users to download new Bing Maps tiles (but only once, allowing them to cache them hereafter)?

As luck would have it, I have a product launch scheduled for tomorrow so I'm hoping desperately that this problem will resolve itself overnight, Australian time...

Comment: If you add a random querystring such as ?123 to the end of your requests then this should force requesting a new tile rather than from cache.

Comment: It is a cache issue - force a cache refresh on your computer (ctrl F5) clear web browser - router can also cache (reboot) or as geographika points to force bing send new tile requests.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question but you should put the solution in an answer and accept it. Don't edit the question to include the answer and add 'resolved'.

Comment: Have rolled back the [resolved] revision as is not good way to indicate the question is answered on GISse - please add an Answer below and accept it - even if the answer is your own.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll change it. FYI, last time I tried to do exactly that, an Administrator deleted my Answer and moved it into the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was unlucky to test this just as ESRI or Microsoft were changing the tiles over, since it works correctly this morning.

The new labels are ugly ugly ugly, and the same shade as the roads (and all of my map controls) but that's another story...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your cache, or running the browser in an incognito mode?